# When do consistent pairwise comparisons imply the existence of a ranking?

Tags: combinatorics, real-analysis

Suppose $|S|=k$ and we have a function $f:S\times S\to \{0,1\}$. The interpretation of $f$ is that $f$ "compares" elements of $S$: $i$ is preferred over $j$ iff $f(i,j)=1$. When does there exist a function $g:S\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
f(i,j)=1 \iff g(i) > g(j)?
$$

It is clear that some type of consistency for $f$ is needed, e.g. $f(i,j)=1-f(j,i)$. I am interested in the minimal set of assumptions (ideally, necessary and sufficient) on $f$ that guarantee the existence of $g$.

Comment: Don't you just need for $f$ to be a total ordering (aka a linear ordering)? This should work as long as $S$ is countable or finite.

Comment: See the list of axioms for a strict total order https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order . "Irreflexive" translates into $f(i,i)=0$; "assymmetric and connected" translates into $f(i,j)+f(j,i)=1$ for $i \neq j$; "transitive" translates to "if $f(i,j)=f(j,k) = 1$ then $f(i,k)=1$ for $i$, $j$, $k$ distinct.